# How to predict performance of a program for smartphones developed on a pc

Tags: android, performance, smartphone

I am developing a program that is going to be very performance-intense for Android/smartphones. Because I do this on a pc (Windows) I do not really know how my application will perform on a mobile device. I do not want to port this program to android until I have a good working version for Windows (this will be my first Android-app and I don't want to try to troubleshoot something when I'm not even sure whether my program is working).

I am searching for some database where I can compare pc-GPUs with mobile GPUs. I know that an accurate comparison is difficult between such different architectures, however, a small hint about the expected performance would be very helpful.

By the way, I am developing on a machine with an integrated  Intel® HD Graphics 4400 and ideally, I want to compare it to something like an Adreno 306.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using benchmarks for the GPU, look at existing cross-platform applications with similar performance and see how it compares. Install it on your computer to make sure the intensiveness is similar (using whatever benchmarks you want), then install it on your android device to see if it can keep up to your expectations. You can find benchmarking apps or you can use the profilers on Android Studio to see how the device in question is handling the application.

This is about as good as you're going to get. Like you said, so much relies on the implementation and the vastly different architecture. Lastly, if you're building on a framework that builds to other platforms (libgdx, xamarin, etc), you should present a specific question to other users of that framework.